# Adding a 3rd button to JOptionPane drop down menu

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

I am relatively new to Java and have been trying to figure out a way to create a JOption window that not only has a drop down option with an "Ok" and "Cancel" button, but also adds an additional button called "Back." So far none of my attempts have successfully been able to add this Back button and every time I run the code it simply brings up the traditional dropdown/ok/cancel type window. Additionally I would also like the window to close when a button has been clicked, but I have been unsuccessful in that as well. Here is the code I have so far, not entirely sure what's missing/wrong with it:

```
public static String sampleWindow(){
    JButton jbt_ok = new JButton("OK");
    JButton jbt_back = new JButton("Back");
    JButton jbt_cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    boolean greyOutBackButton = false;

    jbt_ok.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("OK was clicked");

        }
    });

    jbt_cancel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Cancel was clicked");

        }
    });

    if(greyOutBackButton)
        jbt_back.setEnabled(false);
    else

        jbt_back.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Back was clicked");

            }
        });

    Object[] options = {jbt_ok, jbt_back, jbt_cancel};

    Object selectionObject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "message", "", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, options, options[0]);

    if (selectionObject == null)
        System.exit(0);
    String selectionString = selectionObject.toString();

    System.out.println("Selection String: "+ selectionString);
    return selectionString;
}
```

Comment: What about method [`showOptionDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) in class `JOptionPane`?

Comment: I have. It looks like showOptionDialog is unable to take both an array of possible selections and an array of button options.